# Font smoothing issues in flatpak Firefox on KDE

Tags: kde, firefox, fonts, wayland, flatpak

I've been trying to write a script to launch Firefox on the Steam Deck from Gaming Mode. Just launching it directly doesn't work well because of how Steam Deck manages the window, so I wrote a script to launch a nested `kwin_wayland` instance and run Firefox through that. It works for the most part, but Firefox isn't doing any sub-pixel rendering of text, so it all looks very pixelated. The weird thing is that fonts natively rendered by KDE display just fine, so I must be missing something when launching Firefox.

This is how I'm launching `kwin_wayland` and Firefox in my script:

```
_DISPLAY_RESOLUTION="$(xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions/ {print $2}')"

exec kwin_wayland --no-lockscreen --drm \
    --width "${_DISPLAY_RESOLUTION%x*}" \
    --height "${_DISPLAY_RESOLUTION#*x}" \
    --xwayland --x11-display "${DISPLAY}" \
    --exit-with-session=" \
        /usr/bin/flatpak run \
            --arch=x86_64 --branch=stable \
            --file-forwarding --die-with-parent \
            --command=firefox org.mozilla.firefox"
```

And this is what I'm doing before that to set up the environment:

```
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$HOME/.local/config/gamescope/firefox
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=$HOME/.config:$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS

mkdir -p $XDG_CONFIG_HOME

cat >$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/kwinrc <<KWINRC
[Windows]
BorderlessMaximizedWindows=true
KWINRC

cat >$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/kwinrulesrc <<KWINRULES
[gamescope-fullscreen-windows]
Description=Fullscreen Windows
closeablerule=2
maximizehoriz=true
maximizehorizrule=2
maximizevert=true
maximizevertrule=2
minimizerule=2
noborder=true
noborderrule=2
position=0,0
positionrule=2
shaderule=2
wmclasscomplete=true
wmclassmatch=2
types=66051
[General]
count=2
rules=1,gamescope-fullscreen-windows
KWINRULES
```

I have the full script [in a GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/stevebrun/f6739e84be26e60dfdf3c0516d580532) if you want to take a look at the full thing.